# Bring view to the front prprogrammaticly

Tags: android, view, imageview, imagebutton, android-framelayout

I am using a frameLayout and trying to bring a view **on** another view programmaticly, when an imageButton is clicked. I use Frame Layout because I have been told that it allows you to put view on each other. However, whaen the button is clicked the imageView is disapeering behind the other view, instead of be in the front. 
here is my layout- "hole" is the imageButton and whenever it is clicked the imageView "goola" needs to move on it.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/hole"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/home0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/goola"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/goola" />
```

here is the JAVA (onClick method)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    ImageButton b=(ImageButton)v;
    int[] location = new int[2];     
    b.getLocationOnScreen(location);

     float startX = location[0];
     float startY = location[1];
        goola.setX(startX);
        goola.setY(startY);
}
```

If someone who has a solution can write a good answer I would be grateful!
Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try calling [View#bringToFront()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront()) on an appropriate View.